# SkSpriteNodes are stacking on top of each other

Tags: skspritenode, scene

I am writing a soccer app which I use an SKScene to display my players and so on. My player nodes are set up with an .sks but I want to add more nodes to the scene when I press a button. The code below is how I add my nodes to the scene and they are displayed,
I am able to drag all the nodes around but when these nodes added in the above function collide with any of the nodes they stick together Like in the image below. The zposition of the player node is 3. I have also to the scene to ignoreSiblingOrder.I have tried implementing physics bodies but that doesn't solve the problem, I have tried changing the zPosition, I have tried adding the nodes under different parents. The current parent of all the nodes is the SKScene.The nodes added in the .sks file do not stack on top each other this only affects the nodes which I have programmatically added. Any ideas on how to stop them from sticking or stacking on top each other?

```
func addDiagonal(image : UIImage, name : String){
    arrowNode = SKSpriteNode()
   arrowNode!.texture = SKTexture(image: image)
   arrowNode!.size = CGSize(width: 65, height: 65)
   arrowNode!.position = CGPoint(x: 153, y: 267)
   arrowNode!.zPosition = 4
   arrowNode!.name = name
   myTrainigArr?.append(arrowNode!)
   self.addChild(arrowNode!)
}
```

[This is what happens when the nodes collide or touch each other](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gC6ED.png)

Comment: From your code it doesn't look like you have added a physicsBody to it, that could be the reason.

Comment: I have tried using a physics bodies and it didn't work. The shirts when the collide with other shirts they don't stick together. This only happens with the nodes I have added progamitcally. Which is the arrow.

Comment: What is actually the desired behaviour? They should never be able to overlap each other? When you drag one shirt across another, is it supposed to push the shirt out of the way or can you move one across the other?

Comment: You are right I believe. I would have liked them to overlap each other but it doesn't seem like it possible. In the 3nd I end up giving all the nodes physics bodies and it stopped them from sticking. Wasn't the desired behavior but a work around I guess.

Comment: They could overlap each other, and they could be dragged individually across other nodes, but as it's not clear what the actual desired behaviour is I can't help you. If the work around works for you though then great.

Comment: How can they be dragged across and overlap other nodes? That is my desired behavior.